# nginx url rewrites for php-urls

Tags: nginx, rewrite

i have to permament redirect some old urls in nginx. the old urls are old-style php urls including a parameter for loading content. they look like this:

```
http://www.foo.com/index.php?site=foo
http://www.foo.com/index.php?site=bar
```

i want to redirect them to other urls like:

```
http://www.foo.com/news
http://www.foo.com/gallery
```

any advice on how i can achieve this? my tries failed. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a direct mapping between old URL parameters and new URL path, you could use such a syntax :

```
location /index.php {
  ...
  try_files $uri /$arg_site =404;
}
```

With such a config, any request starting with`/index.php` will first be tried againt the exact URL, then if there's no matching file or location, nginx will try an internal redirect with `/foo` if the original URL is `/index.php?site=foo`. If that fails too, nginx will send a `404 HTTP Not Found` response.

The variable `$arg_site` is set to the value of the URL parameter `site`.

Comment: okay thanks. actually the old and the new urls aren't the same. so e.g. index.php?site=foo AND index.php=site=bar should redirect to /home.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this issue by using php and not the nginx rewrite functionality:

```
if (isset($_GET["site"]) {
  switch ($_GET["site"]) {
    case 'foo':
      Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
      Header( "Location: /foo" ); 
      break;

     ...
  }
}
```